# Swapping a number pad from telephone to synth

Tags: pcb, telephone, synthesizer

I’ve recently acquired from the trash a toy synth keyboard piano.
It works, but I wanted to create a stand-alone number pad from an old telephone.
I’d like to know if it’s possible and how to do it if so.
The telephone runs out through an 11 wire ribbon cable, but there’s nothing similar on the destination chipboard.
I’ve followed all the number pads to their solder points but before i go guessing and checking I thought i’d ask here first. Just beginning to solder and mess around with musi -related stuff, btw.

[image: telephone]

[image: piano]

Comment: It's not clear what the numpad and your synthesizer keyboards are supposed to have to do with each other. Would you please explain?

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to dial the phone from the synthesizer keyboard. In order to do that, you're going to have to figure out how the keys are "matrixed" on both boards, and map from one to the other. It'll probably require a lot of cuts and jumpers in order to get a sane layout.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I want to dial in numbers to the synth

Comment: One major problem with finding out how they are matrixed is that i can’t find the farfisa sk-500 service manual, probably pretty rare since it was a cheap toy.

Comment: A synth doesn't take numbers?

Comment: Such a manual will simply not exist. Nor have ever existed.

Comment: The synth takes numbers. I wrote them on the pcb when i was trying to trace them. They are visible in the second image.

Comment: what do you plan to do with the finished project? ...

Comment: Build a wooden housing around it, make a stand-alone volume-treble-bass knobs, install better speakers, run 1/4 jacks out to a wah pedal and guitar pedal.

Answer (score 1):

To dial telephones you need to make two sine tones at the same time and superimpose them.  search on the term `DTMF` for details.  An electrical connection to the telephone is not needed. playing the tones into the microphone is sufficient.

The keypad in your telephone is not making the tones, that is done by whatever is on the other end of that 11 way cable.  if you merely want to replace the telephone keys with the synthesiser keys you will need to figure out how each is wired and make the appropriate interconnections.

Comment: “  if you merely want to replace the telephone keys with the synthesiser keys you will need to figure out how each is wired and make the appropriate interconnections.”
This is exactly what I want to do. I’m just having trouble finding the interconnections because the destination synth doesn’t have a logical placement of the solder points on the pcb. Thanks!!

Comment: I’m guessing the solution is to break up the 11 wires and “go fishing” to figure out which button is which.

Comment: Where it's not clearly visibile the connections can probably be measured with a ohmmeter.

Comment: Ok i’ll try that thanks.